# React Native problem when usign expo-auth-session

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0, build, expo

When i build the app in my smartphone i get this error. I'm using Expo with and android divice.
If i take away this part, the app works just fine :

`const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useAuthRequest({ androidClientId:'', iosClientId:'', expoClientId:'',   //Here i have my ids. })`

Error: Exception in HostObject::get for prop 'ExpoCrypto': java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert js value to enum without the primary constructor, js engine: hermes

This is my code looks like :

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import * as Google from 'expo-auth-session/providers/google'
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser'
import React from 'react'

WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();

export default function App() {
 const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = React.useState()
 const [data, setData] = React.useState()

 const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useAuthRequest({
  androidClientId:'',
  iosClientId:'',
  expoClientId:'',   //Here i have my ids.
 })

 React.useEffect(()=>{
  if(response?.type === 'success'){
    setAccessToken(response.authentication?.accessToken)
  }
 },[response])

 function showUserInfo(){
  if(data){
    return (
    <View>
      <Text>Welcome {data.name} </Text>
    </View>
    )
  }
 }
 
 async function getUserData(){
  let userInfoResponse = await fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me",{
    headers:{
      Authorization :`Bearer ${accessToken}`
    }
  });
 userInfoResponse.json().then(data => setData(data))
 }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {showUserInfo()}
      <Button
      title={accessToken ? "Get user data" : "Login"}
      onPress = {accessToken ? getUserData : () => promptAsync({showInRecents:true})}
      />
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Answer (score -1):

expo-crypto is a dependency  of expo-auth-session, I tried following the error to the requireNativeModule.js
Kindle check the code init and see if you comment it out